# Is there any Stack Exchange site for mobile's special features disussion?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, stack-exchange

> I just realized that it's possible for companies (e.g. **Xiaomi**,
> **OnePlus**) to include their own *special* features to their android phones.
>
> My **Xiaomi Mi 9T Pro** has some special features include (GameTurbo,
> Floating window, etc.), but the company only provides one way to use
> it, obviously, there are many different phones that come with special
> features. My question is, do Stack Exchange sites have any site for
> using/developing those features?

I already have a question about my phone's special features, but I didn't find any Stack Exchange site, that is specific to ask that kind of question.

Comment: There is an android site, but be sure to check their on-topic before posting there

Comment: For programming each manufacturer has an SDK to match the phone's UI; there's more than one site for MIUI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/miui?tab=Newest has more questions than https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miui about programming / altering / etc. - General end-user questions like "which setting do I change" would probably be more appropriate on Android.SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding using Android phone features, check out [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com). From their [tour page](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour):

> **Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for users of the Android operating system. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Android.
>
> Have a programming question? Visit our sister site, Stack Overflow.

From their [What topics can I ask about? page](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange is for users of the Android operating system.
>
> If your question generally covers...
>
> - Using your Android device
> - Using a particular app on your Android device
> - Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your Android device
>
> then this is the right place to ask. Basically, what problem (with your Android device) are you trying to solve?

For developing features for mobile phones, that is a very broad topic. See [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289691)

Comment: thank you very much for helping, that was exactly what I wanted to know :)